# product details page with different variations

Tags: design, e-commerce, color, product

i am working on a product details page for an ecommerce website and i am dealing with complicated products like (sofa , bed ..etc) in these pages we have a lot of variation regarding colors and sizes.

can you suggest complicated benchmark product details page with different variations i can review ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I Feel for all the product you can't have one template. First list out all the features of the product and choose the common one. Decide the template based on the common feature and present the product page. For example if its 1000 product, it fall in to 50 Category. Based on the category and common feature it will fall into around 5 to 10 template.

It really needs some research work to come up with final answer, hope this helps to get you final answer.

Some reference for you to strengthen the product page - https://www.shopify.com/blog/16204608-7-effective-ecommerce-product-pages-how-to-turn-visitors-into-customers

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you want to consider the simplest and most complex products in terms of:

1. Variations
   What is the product with the least attributes? (like a chair with no color or size choices)

What is the product with the most attributes? (a chair with color, height, width, number of legs, material, cover, etc choices)

2. Bundles
   Are there products which are really a group of products which can be purchased separately? (Like a desk with leg choices, drawer mechanism choices, etc etc etc which can all be purchased ad parts as well)

Or a bundle with choices for 3,5,7 item choices. Meaning bundles of 3,5 or 7 and then you can pick what items those should be.

---

Identify those first, it will allow you to design for both extremes and decide on how many product detail page variations you need.

Comment: Thanks for your input , on of the problems i also face is i have available and non available options on the same page, for example a chair with 3 options to configure.

Comment: @ahmedmansi for those you can simply grey out the options so the user can see you offer it but is currently out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a product that has a big range of available choices, in color or sizes for example, you could do something like below.. (pic1) or more of an Amazon approach of providing drop downs for available choices, and then a details section that changes with the user selection.

Pic 1 :

[image]

Pic 2 (Amazon approach)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Dizzying options a click away

Zappos does a pretty nice job of dealing with this problem. Many of the shoes they carry are available in all sorts of color combinations and sizes. There are also plenty of related products that, to some extent, are part of the whole purchase consideration and should be readily available even from the detail page.

[image: Zappos product detail UI]

They've done a great job of providing visual navigation that configures the configuration on the right. The cart button stays in an active state even when the size has not been configured, but pops hint text on the size selector on hover.

They have wide-ranging cross-sells in the lower part of the right column and very directly related cross-sells just below the product description. The latter category is what I would propose is almost like more product options in the shoe market and possibly for your furniture as well.